# Can I make an OS X Glut app that doesn't open a terminal window?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, glut

I have a lot of simple C++ programs that I've written in XCode, using OpenGL and Glut to visualise scientific data. It works very well, but there is one minor annoyance: every time I run one of the binaries from outside of XCode, it opens a Terminal window. This means I get a crusty build-up of Terminal windows that has to be cleaned up after use.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I'm hoping for a quick solution to a very minor problem, so anything that requires me to learn Objective C or some fancy GUI creation tool isn't what I want. I just want to know if there's a way to compile my existing C++ Glut apps in such a way that the terminal window won't appear when you click on the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of...   Basically, you need some kind of OS X wrapper to contain the binary.   You can do this with Automator or AppleScript or with a tool like [DropScript](http://www.wsanchez.net/software/), which is designed to encapsulate unix binaries.

Otherwise, the solution for this would be to create a minimal Objective-C program and then she'll out the unix binary from within it, so that when it terminates it doesn't leave any residue.